# Input methods in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I was trying to get continuous touch motion in Kivy to move a rectangle for which I wrote a code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Game(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color=(0,1,0,1)
            self.player=Rectangle(pos=(50,0),size=(20,50))



#touch and motion of our player
    def on_motion(self,etype,motionevent,**kwargs):
        print('hello')
        touch_condition=False
        x_touch=motionevent.spos[0]
        xa=self.player.pos[0]
        ya=self.player.pos[1]
        if etype=='begin' or etype=='update':
            touch_condition=True
        if etype=='end':
            touch_condition=False


        if touch_condition and x_touch>0.5:
            xa+=10
        if touch_condition and x_touch<0.5:
            xa-=10      

        self.player.pos=(xa,ya)

    Window.bind(on_motion=on_motion)



class Try(App):
    def build(self):
        return Game()

if __name__=="__main__":
    Try().run()
```

On mouse click as an input its giving an error

> File "kiv.py", line 21, in on_motion
>        xa=self.player.pos[0]  AttributeError: 'WindowSDL' object has no attribute 'player'

I read all documentation on Kivy inputs and `Window.bind` but I am still unable to understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class structure is messed up, you're binding `on_motion` at the class level. I'm surprised this is the error you get, but that looks like the problem.

Add `Window.bind(on_motion=self.on_motion)` in the `__init__` of your Game widget instead.